# React Router add condition if route is not present

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router

I am new to the react-redux. Here I am using the following thing for showing the 404 not found if the given route does not matches.

now, In this

My `App.js`

```
class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Provider store={store}>
                <div className="container-fluid">
                    <Header />
                    <Main />
                </div>
            </Provider>
        )
    }
}
```

My **Main.js**

```
 render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Router history={history}>
          <div>
            {this.props.isFetching && <Loading />}
            <Switch>
              <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={LandingScreen} />
              <PrivateRoute exact path="/quiz-setup" component={QuizSetupMain} />
              <PrivateRoute exact path="/quiz-questions" component={FetchedQuestionComponent} />
              <Route exact path="/login" component={LoginComponent} />
              <Route exact path="/*" component={NotFound} something="foo" />
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </Router>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

**NotFound.js**

import React from 'react';

```
export default class NotFound extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <h1>Something Went Wrong</h1>
    );
  }
}
```

Now , here when user hits any route which is not present then it shows that 404 not found, but it also shows the header part as well. I know that , its because I have rendered both header and main in the app.js file, and not found is in the main, but is there any way to not show that header , if the route is not matched  . thanks

Comment: Please provide us the code of the `NotFound` component

Comment: @lellefood updated the question

Answer (score 1):

You can add function, which returns Component after Header.

for example:

```
const withHeader = (Component) => {
  return class withHeaderComponent extends React.Component{ render() { return (<div><Header /><Component /></div>)}}
}
```

after creating this function, you can use it like,

```
<Route exact path="/login" component={withHeader(LoginComponent)} />.
```

So you are able to add header for Routes you want.

```
<Route component={NotFound}/>
```

Now your 404 will be without Header !

Let me know if you face difficulties.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the component of dynamic components.

The idea is, every route path that is called, navigates through a common component which invokes suitable behaviour based on the component called. For example -

```
              <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={CustomComponent} />
```

and then pass props accordingly to determine, which screen has to render the header component.

So, essentially, your code will look something like this -

```
class App extends React.Component {
render() {
    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
            <div className="container-fluid">
                <Main />
            </div>
        </Provider>
       )
   }
}
```

and the `<Header/>` component will be called in custom component based on appropriate conditions that you put forward

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a wildcard to redirect people to not found page the route is not accessible.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Switch } from 'react-router';
import { BrowserRouter , Route ) from 'react-router-dom;
import NotFound from './NotFound';

const routes = (   
               <BrowserRouter>
                  <Switch>
                     <Route path="*" component={NotFound}/>
                  </Switch>
                </BrowserRouter>
               )
```

Comment: The only thing you actually have to add is `<Route path="*" component={NotFound}/>` to your routes and pass the component you want to show as props when the page is not available.